# MVC 5 nested dropdownlist(county-town) don't filtering second dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I can get county and town from database.But when I choose county from first dropdownlist,second is not filtered depending on first one.When ajax is running,it jumps error directly.Then it gives 'Hata' alert.Following code is from controller.

```
public class AfetGirisController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /AfetGiris/
    MVCAfetGirisContext db = new MVCAfetGirisContext();

    public ActionResult YeniKayit()
    {

        //ViewBag.iller = new SelectList(db.Ils.ToList(), "IlId", "IlAd");
        List<string> iller= new List<string>();
        ViewBag.iller = new SelectList(db.Ils.ToList(), "IlId", "IlAd");
        List<string> ilceler = new List<string>();
        ViewBag.ilceler = new SelectList(db.Ilces.ToList(), "IlceId", "IlceAd");
        return View();//değiştirdim
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Ilcler(int ilid)
    {
        using (MVCAfetGirisContext db = new MVCAfetGirisContext())
        {
            // seçilen ulkenin id sine eşit olan şehirler seciliyor.
            List<Ilce> ilcem = db.Ilces.Where(x => x.Il.IlId == ilid).ToList();

            // şehirler listesini Json olarak gönderiyoruz.
            return Json(ilcem);
        }
    }
```

Scripts;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#iller').change(function () {
        var ilid = $(this).val();
        if (ilid != null && ilid != '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: '@Url.Action("Ilcler", "AfetGirisController")',
                data: { ilid: ilid },
                success: function (ilcem) {
                    $('#ilceler').empty()
                    $.each(ilcem, function (YeniKayit, ilce) {
                        $('#ilceler').append($('<option/>', {
                            value: ilce.IlceId,
                            text: ilce.IlceAd
                        }));
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Hata");
                },
                beforeSend: function () {},
                complete: function () {}
            });
        }
    });
});
```

then,

```
@Html.DropDownList("iller",ViewBag.iller as SelectList,"---İl---", new { style = "width:250px; height:28px;" })<br /><br />
@Html.DropDownList("ilcem", ViewBag.ilceler as SelectList, "---İlce---", new { style = "width:250px; height:28px;" })<br /><br />
```

Comment: Which means your throwing an exception. Use you browser tools to determine the error. And you should not be returning `List<Ilce>` - just an collection of anonymous objects containing only the 2 properties you need.

Comment: And you you really have a controller named `AfetGirisControllerController`? - I suspect its really `AfetGirisController` which means it needs to be `url: '@Url.Action("Ilcler", "AfetGiris")',`

Comment: yes Controller's name is AfetGirisController as you see abow.How can I see exception with browser tools.And why i should not be returning List<Ilce>

Comment: (1) Therefore you will be getting a 404 Not Found error in the browser console (it needs to be `url: '@Url.Action("Ilcler", "AfetGiris")',`). (2) You should not be writing scripts unless you know how to debug them. For Chrome, [start here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) (3) Because your degrading performance sending extra data across the wire which you never even use.